# LAN speed slow on Ubuntu 18.04, but Internet speed is fine

Tags: 18.04, connection, lan

I have a dell laptop that is a dual boot system. It has Ubuntu 18.04 64 bit and windows 10.
For some reason, in the last 10 days or so, the lan speed on the ubuntu system has slowed by factor of almost 10. The internet speed is fine.
I booted into windows 10 and performed some tests and they were fine, so I can rule out any hardware or cabling issues. I'm not an ubuntu guru, so it is possible I messed something up.

I ran iperf3 from ubuntu partition to another machine on lan.
speed averaged 22 to 45 mbits

I ran iperf from windows partition to another machine on lan
speed averaged 600 mbits

Note: ubuntu and windows are on same system so using same ethernet card and same cabling

I ran ethtool and here is output

sudo ethtool eno1
Settings for eno1:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: on (auto)
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes

again, it was fine around 10 days ago. I know I have re-installed ffmpeg and cuda on the system, and probably messed around with the .xauthority file, but not sure if any of this is the cause.

Any suggestions?